# requires android.permission.ACCESS_ALL_DOWNLOADS, or grantUriPermission()

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider, android-permissions

When I'm going select a file from all downloads folder and then getting file path from uri using content provider getting following permission denied issue below

```
Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadProvider uri content://downloads/all_downloads/1092 from pid=31615, uid=10228 requires android.permission.ACCESS_ALL_DOWNLOADS, or grantUriPermission()
```

using following code

```
String[] contentUriPrefixesToTry = new String[]{
                "content://downloads/public_downloads",
                "content://downloads/my_downloads",
                "content://downloads/all_downloads"
        };
        final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
        String path = null;
        for (String uriPath : contentUriPrefixesToTry) {
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse(uriPath), Long.valueOf(id));
            String lastPathSagment = uri.getLastPathSegment();
            InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            File file = new File(context.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + lastPathSagment);
            writeFile(inputStream, file);
            path = file.getAbsolutePath();
             if (path != null) {
             return path;
             }
        }
```

Comment: Where is `uri` coming from? How are you getting that value?

Comment: @CommonsWare uri is content://downloads/all_downloads/1234

Comment: That didn't answer my questions. After all, you aren't hard-coding that `Uri`, since it will not exist on all devices. So, somehow, you are getting that value at runtime. How are you doing this?

Comment: @CommonsWare uri is not hard coded its example uri, i have updated question please check

Comment: If your target version above `>=24` then you need to use _FileProvider_.

Answer (score 3):

I had the above issue, but found a solution. I was using ACTION_GET_CONTENT to pick a file from external storage, but it does not work in Android 7 and above. Someone guided me to use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT to pick a file, and now it's working fine for me.

Intent PDF Picker:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <19) {
        Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        pdfIntent.setType("application/pdf");
        startActivityForResult(pdfIntent, PICK_PDF);
    } else {
        Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        pdfIntent.setType("application/pdf");
        pdfIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(pdfIntent, PICK_PDF);
    }
```

Code to get File Path:

```
    if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
        String fileName = getFilePath(context, uri);
        if (fileName != null) {
            return String.format("%s/Download/%s", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), fileName);
        }

        String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
        if (id.startsWith("raw:")) {
            id = id.replaceFirst("raw:", "");
            File file = new File(id);
            if (file.exists())
                return id;
            }
        }

        final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
        return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
    }
```

Methods used in above code:

```
    public static String getFilePath(Context context, Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String[] projection = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
                return cursor.getString(index);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = { column };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Your code is 'trying' to access that directory to see if it exists, and even open an inputstream to get the supposed File. If the directory doesn't exist Android will be displeased with you and tell you that you're not allowed to access that dir. 
No need to request permission as the dir does not exist.